# Cannot fetch some special characters from mysql table in codeigniter

Tags: php, html, mysql, codeigniter

I have a issue while fetching some data from the mysql table whose data type is "text".
What i have is a portal for instructor and student. Student will ask question and the instructor can answer them by text or put some code in that.
Say If a student has asked a demo code for php echo so the instructor can put the code

```
<?php echo "Hello World!" ?>
```

The issue is this answer is saved in database but when i'm trying to fetch, I can't fetch the result.
The problem is if I put '<' & '?' together the code is not fetched but when I put space in between them then it is fetched.
I have tried many things like my charset in config of database

```
'char_set' => 'UTF8',
'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
```

Then my meta

```
<meta charset=utf-8"/>
```

I have tried everything but i cant really fetch it.
My model code to fetch the answer is

```
public function getAnswer($questionId)
{
    $this->db->select('answer');
    $this->db->from('tbl_que_ans as qa');
    $this->db->where('qa.questionId', $questionId);
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $query_result = $query->row();
    return $query_result;
}
```

While displaying it in the view i'm using foreach

```
<?php foreach ($answeredQuestions as $key) {
      echo $key->answer;
?>
```

This how my datatable looks:
[image: There is data in answer column. Thats how my data is going to be.]
I'm not able make it work. Can somebody please help me in this.
Thanks already!!

Comment: post example of your data

Comment: I have edited and put a screenshot of the data in the datatable.

Comment: whats error running now ??

Comment: So what I get in this case is My answer is displayed till "PHP is life" the code after that is not displayed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try this

`echo htmlspecialchars($key->answer);`

or

`echo htmlentities($key->answer);`

Answer (score 3):

do like this

```
<?php foreach ($answeredQuestions as $key) 
{
      echo htmlspecialchars($key->answer);
}
```

Read more about [PHP `htmlspecialchars()` Function in W3school.com](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_htmlspecialchars.asp)